# Python reading and writing sound frequencies to wav files

Tags: python, wav, frequency

I'm new to python programming & have no knowledge at all of creating and working with sound files.

I am looking for some help with the following:

Using python I want to be able to create a wav file and write sound frequencies to that file.

In another part of the program I am writing I also want to be able to read back those sound frequencies.

Also knowing nothing about sound what so ever. If it right sound frequencies to a file. Are sound frequencies on there own enough to create a sound on playback, or is additional data required?

Also the values contained within the file I am using are very low values. as low as zero, so to make them audible I assume I would have to add an additional value to the value read from the file in order to hear that frequency on playback?

Thanks in advance for any help that I receive!

Clinton.

Comment: I would suggest to read some basics about digital audio, time domain and frequency domain. .wav- files are PCM- data, that means, the audio signal is stored in form of samples (mostly in the form of signed shorts). So you can't write "frequencies". You have to write samples, the value represents the amplitude of the signal and the delta from one sample and the following samples encodes the frequency. This information only to give you a basic overview.

Comment: ok, so using a sample of some sort I could them write various frequcies to that sample? If this is correct that works ok for me as I'm not trying to create music. Would this work?

Comment: No...a sample represents the state of the audio signal at one discrete point in time. Please make yourself familiar with the basics of digital audio, maybe this link helps you: http://dspwiki.com/index.php?title=Main_Page